# Bluetooth earphone is connected, but has no sound after shutdown and restart

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, device-manager

I am currently trying to fix this issue with my friend, but we are now stuck and don't know what to do.

Our teacher uses a Bluetooth earphone (**Xiaomi Haylou GT1 PRO TWS**) for her everyday tasks. It ran smoothly without problems, but after some time, her hard disk is found to be having a bad sector. It was successfully repaired by her colleagues at school.

After it was repaired, this problem occurs. Her earphone is connected, but it has no sound at all.

We followed some tips and instructions [we found here](http://www.headphonesty.com/2020/08/bluetooth-headphones-connected-but-no-sound/#How_to_Fix_Bluetooth_headphones_connected_but_no_sound_in_PC), to fix the issue, and somehow it solved the problem.

But, whenever our teacher shuts down her laptop, the same problem keeps repeating: earphone is connected, but no sound.  We have no idea why the Bluetooth setting is never 'saved' properly on her laptop.

How to keep this Bluetooth setting permanent again? What can we do?

Additional concern: does performing Windows Update have some kind of impact with this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the exact make and model of the Bluetooth headset? Without knowing that basic info, I doubt anyone here can really helpful.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll edit this question later after I got the exact model of the headset.